# how to decompress gzipped contents in JAVA

Tags: java, gzip

In HTTP request and response, content-encoding is 'gzip' and content is gzipped. Is there a way to decompress the gzipped content so we can see the contents ??

Example for GZipped HTTP request

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: mon, 15 Jul 2014 22:38:34 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.3.7 (Unix)  (Red-Hat/Linux)
Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Jan 2003 23:11:55 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 438
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: gzip

//Response body with non type characters
```

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-decompress-file-from-gzip-file/

Comment: google is your friend. The automatic suggestions when you ask your question - also

Comment: The question here is why the application container doesn't do that transparently.

Comment: The answer is I'm writing the Application container. A simple HTTP server using Socket programing. Pretty interestingm isn't..

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be necessary. Your application server should handle such requests for you and decompress the payload for you automatically.

If that doesn't happen, you need to wrap the `InputStream` in a `GZipInputStream`. But this sounds more like a misconfiguration of your server.

Comment: I'm writing the web server container. A simple HTTP server using Socket programing.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

```
//reply - Response from Http  byte[] reply = getResponseBytes();
 int i;
             for(i=0;i<reply.length;i++){
              //Finding Raw Response by two new line bytes
                 if(reply[i]==13){
                     if(reply[i+1]==10){
                         if(reply[i+2]==13){
                             if(reply[i+3]==10){
                                 break;
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }

             }
             //Creating new Bytes to parse it in GZIPInputStream  
             byte[] newb = new byte[4096];
             int y=0;
             for(int st=i+4;st<reply.length;st++){
                 newb[y++]=reply[st];
             }
                       GZIPInputStream  gzip = new GZIPInputStream (new ByteArrayInputStream (newb));
                        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(gzip);
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);

                        String readed;
                        while ((readed = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            //Bingo...
                            System.out.println(readed);
                        }
```